# PHP, IDE, MySQL, Curl API and apache installation

Tags: php, mysql, apache, curl

Is any installer which can configure PHP, IDE, MySQL,Curl API  and Apache. my goal is to use Curl API using PHP. I am lots of trouble with manual installing.

Comment: what platform are you on? Linux? Mac? Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows - use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com)

Linux - just use the native package manager

Mac - use [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) or [XAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) if you must

As for IDE's id Grab Eclipse+PDT (theres a nifty [all-in-one binary](http://www.zend.com/community/pdt?ecl=EclipseZend)) or NetBeans... i prefer Eclipse myself.

IF you dont need a full IDE but jsut a good text editor I like Textmate on OSX and E on Windows... for linux i never found one i liked really (ie. Texamate for Linux haha).

Comment: I have installed WAMP and eclipse. But can i let the eclipese installtion that i should use the wamp files for php and apche

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you mean... are you talking about debugging?

Answer (score 2):

i don't recommend you using a specific IDE unless you need those features.
consider eclipse php

edit:
for quick development on Windows i'd rather use EasyPHP, it's faster and lighter than WAMP IMO

Comment: Who does'nt want code completion? highlighting? Project organisation?

Comment: the point is "unless you need those". small project can be done without them with similar time, using notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend if u  want extra facilities some time curl needs to run faster so what we do is use threading in zend there are trick of it that none other has.
EASYPHP will do the magic 
SugarCRM --> hmmm is heavy and add more time to development